# common mistakes with induction proofs specifically inequalities

Tags: proof-writing

I have a question involving a tempting method when proving the statement: $2^{n}>n^{2},$ for $n \geq 5.$

basis step: we can show that when $n=5,$ LHS: 32, RHS: 25, so our base case holds.

Induction hypothesis: let us assume that: $2^{k}>k^{2},$ is true for some $k\geq 5.$

Induction step: This implies by induction, that: $2^{(k+1)}>(k+1)^{2}.$

Please comment on the following proof.

Proof: notice $2^{k+1} = 2\times 2^{k}.$ Hence we have: $2\times 2^{k} =  2k^{2}.$

By showing that if $2k^{2}>(k+1)^{2}, k\geq 5$ it must follow that: $2k^{2}>(k+1)^{2},k\geq 5.$

\begin{align}
2k^{2}&>(k+1)^{2}\\
&=k^{2}+2k+1\\
2k^{2}&>k^{2}+2k+1\\
k^{2}-2k-1>0.\\
\end{align}

This inequality is true for $k\geq 3.$

What is wrong with the step, that if we can show that $2k^{2}>(k+1)^{2},$ that we can hence show that $2\times 2^{k}>(k+1)^{2}?$

is starting by showing that $2k^{2}>(k+1)^{2}, k\geq 5$ invalid to write down? And, in general is this a common mistake in inequality proofs?

Comment: When you wrote that $2\times2^k=2k^2$, did you mean to write that $2\times2^k\color{red}>2k^2$?

Comment: The induction step need only work for $k\ge 5$ because there is the induction start. Since the step works for $k\ge 3$ , it also works for $k\ge 5$ , so everything is fine.

Comment: sorry, yes I meant 2×2^{k}>2k^{2}

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is that you are correct, however it is better to be more explicit of what you are doing. I will show you two proofs and yours as transparent as possible, I think part of the confusion comes from the use of logical ifs and only ifs (iffs) and implications.

We want to see that $2^n > n^2$, for any $n \geq 5$.

Proof by induction.

1. Case base: $n = 5$.
   In this case we see that $2^n = 2^5 = 32 > 25 = 5^2 = n^2$. Therefore case base its fulfilled.
2. Induction hypothesis (IH): let's asume that $2^k > k^2$ for a fixed $k > 5$.
3. We need to prove that

$$2^{k+1} > (k+1)^2 \quad (I)$$

In order to show (I), there are at least 3 ways.

**First way**

We start with the IH (which we have assumed to be true) and work our way with logical **implications** until we arrive at (I):

\begin{align*}
2^k > k^2 & \Rightarrow 2(2^k) > 2(k^2)\\
& \Rightarrow 2^{k+1} > 2k^2 \quad (*)\\
\end{align*}
Using the fact that, $k^2 > 2k +1$ for $k > 5$ (this is the Lema you used in your proof), we see that $2k^2 > k^2 + 2k + 1 = (k+1)^2$, from this and what we had in $(*)$, we see that $2^{k+1} > 2k^2 > (k+1)^2$, and (by transitivity) we are done, so using logical implications we arrived at what we wanted to prove in (I).

**Second way**

We start with what we want to prove (I), and work our way with logical **ifs and only ifs** until we arrive at something that's either true or easier to prove (we need the IH at some point):

\begin{align*}
2^{k+1} > (k+1)^2 & \iff 2^{k+1} > k^2 + 2k + 1\\
& \iff 2(2^{k}) > k^2 + 2k + 1\\
& \iff 2^{k} +  2^k > k^2 + 2k + 1\\
& \iff 2^{k} > 2k + 1 \; (\text{here, we used the IH})
\end{align*}

Therefore if we prove that $2^{k} > 2k + 1$ for $k > 5$ (this is an easy to prove lema also by induction)  by the iffs, we are done.

**Your way**

Your way is correct, although it would look more crystal clear if you phrase it like this:

On the one hand, by the induction hypothesis we have that $2^k > k^2$, then

\begin{align*}
2^k > k^2 & \Rightarrow 2(2^k) > 2k^2\\
& \Rightarrow 2^{k+1} > 2k^2 \quad (**)
\end{align*}

On the other hand, we assure that $2k^2 > (k+1)^2$, to see this, we use **ifs and only ifs** (the "second way" method described above), indeed

\begin{align*}
2k^2 > (k+1)^2 & \iff 2k^2 > k^2 + 2k +1\\
& \iff 2k^2 -k^2 -2k - 1 > 0\\
& \iff k^2 -2k - 1 > 0
\end{align*}
Since this last inequality is true, it follows by the iffs that indeed, $2k^2 > (k+1)^2$, from this last fact and what we had in (**), we have $2^{k+1} > 2k^2 > (k+1)^2$, and by transitivity we are done!

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, this really helped!